# Project Euler module

Tags: python, modules

I use Project Euler to teach me programming and not to submit any results. As such I look up the expected return values to double check my solutions.

To organise my files I use the following folder structure:

> ```
> main.py
> \euler # The problem files
>      __init__.py # empty
>      e001.py
>      e002.py
>      ...
> \input # Additional input files
>      8.dat
>      11.dat
>      ...
> ```

My `main.py` file is the common entry point. It can either run all the solved examples so far or a specific one. This second option is added that I don't need to add an `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard in every file. The file looks as follows:

```
TOP_LEVEL = "euler"

def run_module(num):
    """Run specific Problem"""
    mod = importlib.import_module('%s.e%0.3i' % (TOP_LEVEL, num))

    start = time.time()
    ist = mod.run()
    print("  %5i | %6.3f |  %s  | %i" % \
(num, time.time() - start, "ox"[ist == mod.SOLL], ist))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N_MAX = 67

    # Pre Header
    print('Problem |  Time  | x/o | Solution')
    print("--------+--------+-----+---------")

    global_time = time.time()

    # Run over all problems
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        run_module(int(sys.argv[1]))
    else:
        for num in range(1, N_MAX + 1):
            run_module(num)

    # End Header
    print("--------+--------+-----+---------")
    print("Total: %.3f s" % (time.time() - global_time))
```

I'll show now two example files to show the source files and how old code can be reused. `e018.py`:

```
"""By starting at the top of the triangle below and moving to adjacent numbers on the row below, the maximum total from top to bottom is 23.

3
7 4
2 4 6
8 5 9 3
That is, 3 + 7 + 4 + 9 = 23.

Find the maximum total from top to bottom of the triangle below"""

SOLL = 1074

def run(file = "input/18.dat"):
    # Parse File
    with open(file) as fid:
        tri = [[int(num) for num in line.split(' ')] for line in fid.read().split('\n')]

    # From bottom's up find the maximal value   
    for row in range(len(tri) - 2, -1, -1):
        for col in range(row + 1):
            tri[row][col] += max(tri[row + 1][col], tri[row + 1][col + 1])

    return tri[0][0]
```

and `e067.py`

```
"""By starting at the top of the triangle below and moving to adjacent numbers on the row below, the maximum total from top to bottom is 23.

3
7 4
2 4 6
8 5 9 3
That is, 3 + 7 + 4 + 9 = 23.

Find the maximum total from top to bottom of the triangle below"""

import e018

SOLL = 7273

def run(file = "input/67.dat"):
    # problem has been solved in set 18
    return e018.run(file = file)
```

Since this is the first time I tried to structure such a project, I'm quite sure there is plenty of room for optimization. I'm happy for any feedback I can get.

Answer (score 3):

**Use `.format`**

Using `%` is considered old style, so:

```
print("  %5i | %6.3f |  %s  | %i".format(
    (num, time.time() - start, "ox"[ist == mod.SOLL], ist)))
```

**Be generous with long variables names**

For example `ist` is impossible to understand for me, `solution` is more natural

**Don't abuse Code-Golf techniques**

The line:

```
"ox"[ist == mod.SOLL]
```

is a well known Code-Golf trick that relies on implicit boolean to integer conversion that is equivalent to:

```
"x" if ist == mod.SOLL else "o"
```

please use the latter.

**Use `argparse`**

C-Style arguments such as `sys.argv[1]` should be avoided, I suggest `argparse` (help to get started here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427101/dead-simple-argparse-example-wanted-1-argument-3-results)

**Don't shadow built-ins**

```
def run(file = "input/18.dat"):
    # Parse File
    with open(file) as fid:
```

`file` is a built-in, you should use `file_` in your code.

**Explode long lines**

Divide the following lines in two please.

```
 tri = [[int(num) for num in line.split(' ')] for line in fid.read().split('\n')]
```

Comment: Thank you for this input. I definitely have to look into the `.format` since I still stick to c formatting all the time. I also started using `argparse` meanwhile and learned to like it. Once thing I'm myself not really certain about is the shadowing of the file variable. A better name might have been `path` anyway but is it really so bad to shadow a builtin for which nearly nobody is ever gonna call its constructor directly? Conserning the data structure I was also wondering if you had any input about that.

Comment: @magu_ it is better not to, because, for example in an IDE `file` will change colour, and seeing an ordinary variable of another colour is distracting

Comment: Yes, I guess your right.